# Vite and Sendbird does not works

Tags: reactjs, vite, sendbird

I got that an app made with React(using `Vite`) and `Sendbird`(A chat provider) works together, but I don't know why, from today this is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
        at node_modules/ws/lib/constants.js (constants.js:5)
        at __require2 (chunk-F5R5HRHB.js?v=62787598:19)
        at node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js (buffer-util.js:3)
        at __require2 (chunk-F5R5HRHB.js?v=62787598:19)
        at node_modules/ws/lib/permessage-deflate.js (permessage-deflate.js:5)
        at __require2 (chunk-F5R5HRHB.js?v=62787598:19)
        at node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js (websocket.js:14)
        at __require2 (chunk-F5R5HRHB.js?v=62787598:19)
        at node_modules/ws/index.js (index.js:3)
        at __require2 (chunk-F5R5HRHB.js?v=62787598:19)
```

Buffer is a type from `@types/node`, that I have installed as a dependency already.

This is the app sample that I do: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-stallman-pd7wj?file=/src/App.jsx

If I do the same app with **CRA**, it is working well, here is a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-heisenberg-pm8me?file=/src/App.js:23-115)

I think, the problem is Vite, but, why now and not before?

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "types": ["vite/client", "node"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/ui/components/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["./src/ui/styles/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Where could be the problem?

Best,
Agus

Comment: are you raise an issue in their GitHub about packages dependencies or any confliction with typescript?

Comment: No, because this is happens from this morning, I thought that was an errror provocated by me, but I think is Vite

Comment: I just add the issue..wait for approve https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5108

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into a very similar issue with Angular Elements + Sendbird. I was able to resolve it [a solution found on the `react-pdf` repository](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1029#issuecomment-740607786).

The gist is that the Buffer polyfill was removed from webpack 4->5 upgrade, and to get the runtime to work several missing packages needed to be installed using:

```
npm install assert browserify-zlib buffer process stream-browserify util
```

Additionally, the webpack configuration needed to be updated as follows:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
 {...}
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            process: 'process/browser',
            stream: "stream-browserify",
            zlib: "browserify-zlib"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
    ]
}
```

For Angular specifically, I had to implement a custom webpack config to add the plugin.

Also, in case it helps, for other missing polyfills (i.e. zlib, crypto, etc.), I was able to use webpack's `resolve.fallback` to set these to `false` as per the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback).